# How to create three column document with visible dividers?

Tags: multicol, columns

I added **\threecolumn** but it doesn't work.

What command will change the document layout to three column format with dividers visible like the following illustration?

```
---------HEADER---------
###### | ###### | ######
###### | ###### | ######
###### | ###### | ######
###### | ###### | ######
###### | ###### | ######
###### | ###### | ######
---------FOOTER---------
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package to do this. It's manual is typeset in three column format! (at least the first half).
A separation line can be added by setting the `\columnseprule` length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{Test}
\lipsum
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\section{Test}
\lipsum


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I am using pictures with \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth] and they are not handled correctly with multicol which renders the package unusable for me. Is there another package or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: @MichaelS. Try either `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth` (or ask a question that shows the problem adding images).

Comment: @Martin Scharrer; Just want to know that, is there any ready-made option available for three column layout as like as `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`

Comment: @MichaelS. Refer this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255260/image-not-showing-up-when-using-figure-environment for inserting images in `multicol`

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]