# Image not showing up when using figure environment

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to add an image to my paper but I have a problem.

When I add the image with just `\includegraphics[]{}` tag, everything works fine, and the picture shows up when I compile my document.

When I use `\begin{figure} \includegraphics[]{} \end{figure}` - syntax the image does not appear in the compiled document.

The relevant part of my header include is :

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {pics/} }
```

And later on I add the image with this block:

```
%This does not work

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{generalPolya}
  \label{generalPolya}
\end{figure}



%This works

\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{generalPolya}
```

I guess it's some sort of issue in the graphics package, but I've copied the setup from a previous paper I had, so it should work.
Any ideas on what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Thanks for all the responses. I created a minimal working example. Apparently multicols messes with the figure tag:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{Lorem ipsum}} % Article title
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Insert title
\begin{multicols}{2} %
%This does not show up
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{generalPolya}
\end{figure}
%This shows up.
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{chair}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

What shows up after compiling the document is this

[image]

What is wrong with this syntax?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: And additionally: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your `\label` in the first code snippet is of no use, since it does not generate a label for your figure -- you have to use `\caption` for a `\label` to be effective there. Here you generate a label for the last counter incremented outside of the `figure` environment, e.g. a `chapter` counter

Comment: Are you sure the float did not just float to a different page? you might also want to use `\begin{figure}[htbp]` as the default (`\begin{figure}`) is the same as `\begin{figure}[tbp]` note no `h` (remember `h` does not mean *HERE*, it means here about)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried `\begin{figure}[htbp]` but it does not work. There is no floating, I checked the whole document. I tried to recreate a minimal working example as you said but there it works, so I guess it has to do with some conflict in my environment headers. I think I'll just keep on adding packages until I isolate the one that causes the issue

Comment: @PanagiotisChatzichristodoulou: `multicols` disables the figure environment, such that nothing shows up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using a minipage as this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
 \captionof{figure}{figure caption}
 \label{fig:fig1}
\end{minipage}
}

\medskip

I used Figure \ref{fig:fig1} above and referred to it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you suggest works, so I'll accept the answer. I still don't understand why this and a simple \includegraphics work, but the figure environment does not compile.

Comment: @PanagiotisChatzichristodoulou: It will remain a mystery if you don't provide the faulty document which caused the error ;-)

Comment: What's the point of including the `makebox` and `mintage` environments?

Answer (score 20):

This is why I like compiling on the command line and not with TeXMaker etc. stuff:

There is a clear warning in the `.log` file (and a often occurring error:) No floats inside `multicols` environment:

```
Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' environment!.
```

This is documented behaviour, the `multicol` manual describes this warning and clearly states what will happen (emphasis mine):

> ```
> Floats and marginpars not allowed inside ‘multicols’ environment!
> ```
>
> This message appears if you try to use the `\marginpar` command or an
>   unstarred version of the `figure` or `table` environment. **Such floats will
>   disappear!**

If a figure (or table) with caption shall be used in a `multicols` environment, then use `\captionof{figure}{Caption text}` instead of `\caption` and omit the `figure` environment completely (or the `table` env.) In this sense, my answer is basically the same as the solution by AboAmmar, but without the box and minipage.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
% I disable this since it's not relevant
%\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{Lorem ipsum}} % Article title
\begin{document}
%  \maketitle % Insert title
\begin{multicols}{2} %
%This does not show up
%\begin{figure}[h]  % Drop this
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{generalPolya}
    \captionof{figure}{My figure which should be inside the multicols}
%\end{figure} % Drop this
%This shows up.
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{chair}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a figure not showing up when using `multicol`

I fixed with the help of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483689/152952

```
\usepackage{float}
[...]
\begin{figure}[H]
    [...]
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the thread that came up when I was looking for the same problem.

My issue was that I had defined the document class as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{article}
```

Removing the **draft** part finally allowed the images to show.

Comment: This would not match OP symptom of the graphic appearing when not used in the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to get a fig. showing in a PDF pre-view in LaTeX Workshop (Vscode). I couldn't get it to show no matter what scale I chose. No error messages occured, and I couldn't see any corresponding warnings in the log.
But once I closed the preview and reopened it, all of a sudden the fig showed. Im thinking it was compiling all the time, but somehow the PDF preview wasn't able to show it. A simple reopening did the trick for me. Maybe this helps someone too.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Pablo, this thread came up while troubleshooting a similar issue.

For those using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) -
if a custom *draft* option is available in a document class it might be worth checking if it conflicts with Overleaf's Fast option (See picture).
In my case setting `draft = true`, `draft = false` or enabling Fast mode were all different, with the Fast option preventing any image from showing.
[image]

Comment: As explained in other answers, problem is use of floats inside `multicols` environment. So, you not solve OP problem ...