# Image will show up with \includegraphics but non with begin figure

Tags: graphics, captions

if I use:

```
\includegraphics{Graph}
```

the image will show up, but not if I use

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Graph}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea why? Missing package? I need it because in the figure I will add the caption and label...

Thanks

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text
 I add the figure.
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics{Graph}
\end{figure}
% \includegraphics{Graph} % with this would work
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Solution:

Don't use begin and and figure.

Use direct \includegraphics{Graph} and on a new line \captionof{figure}{the caption}\label{textorefer}

Thanks all for the help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems strange, do you get any warnings? Sure the floating `figure` isn't just pushed to the end of the document, or some other location?

Comment: I wrote includegrapichx in the title but in my code is not wrong: Includegraphics

Comment: You can edit the question/title if you want to fix such things, or add additional info.

Comment: Are you using `\begin{multicols}...\end{multicols}` wrapping around the `figure` environment? If yes, you're lost, since `multicols` disables the figure

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Is not in strange location, and in the same location will show up with the shorten command

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: in the minimal working example both figures are working... And I had just copy paste the commands...

Comment: Start with a copy of your original document. Then remove bits of the content of the document, all the while making sure that the problem persists. If the problem disappears, undo the last change. Keep doing that until you've removed as much as possible. Do the same for the preamble, removing all packages, definitions etc. that do not influence the problem. In the mean time, you could edit the question to include the contents of the `.log` file.

Comment: Ok, this is the smallest I get with the same problem!

Comment: Very clear, and @ChristianHupfer already guessed the answer in a previous comment. See also [Image not showing up when using figure environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255273)

Comment: but if I drop it how can I refer to the figure?

Comment: sorry I solved it!!!