# eps images position in IEEEtrans class

Tags: floats, positioning, ieeetran, warnings

I have a document with some problems in the positions of the last images. I copied the code here and after that, I copy the warnings that I get:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\IEEEPARstart whatever


whatever

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=75mm]{uno.eps}
\caption{uno (5 paths, length 31 m-sequence)
}
\label{fig:uno}
\end{figure}


text text text

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=75mm]{dos.eps}
\caption{dos
}
\label{fig:dos}
\end{figure}

text text text:


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=75mm]{tres.eps}
\caption{tres
}
\label{fig:tres}
\end{figure}

text text:

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=75mm]{cuatro.eps}
\caption{cuatro
}
\label{fig:cuatro}
\end{figure}

text text text:

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=75mm]{cinco.eps}
\caption{cinco
}
\label{fig:cinco}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This is the warning:

> LaTeX Warning: 'h' float specifier changed to 'ht'

Please, let me know if you need more details. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I don't see how you would get that warning with the code you've posted, none of the floats have just `h` as specifier.

Comment: there is no space in the page where the first image should go. so I guess it should leave a blank space and then put the image and the rest of the text in a new page, but it doens't

Comment: No, that is what the `figure` environment does. It is a *floating* environment, meaning that LaTeX will move it around to avoid just such bad page breaks, that would leave you with a lot of extra whitespace at the bottom of a page.

Comment: so the only solution is trying to make it to have the image in a place where there is enough space?

Comment: No. The normal thing to do is to let LaTeX place the floats, and use cross references (`figure~\ref{fig:uno} shows ...`) to refer to the figures. There are several ways of restricting this though, see [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275). For example as mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2281/586) you can add `\usepackage{float}` and use `H` as the float specifier, that disables floating. Another option is to not use a float at all, see for example [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255260).

Comment: I've tried all those alternatives and none of them work. I use the packages float, afterpage and placeins and I use: \clearpage
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
  \includegraphics...  but it doesn't work :(

Comment: even if I put /newpage somewhere else, it just ignores it